# Unexpected exit() in a return-oriented programming attempt?

Tags: c, linux, security, memory, low-level

I tried to repeat a part of [this tutorial](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/28/introduction-to-return-oriented-programming-rop.html#fnref:4) on an x86_64 system. Here are my attempts:

```
[13:01:27][/tmp]$ ps | grep $$  
24471 pts/2    00:00:00 zsh
[13:01:31][/tmp]$ cat test.c
void not_called() {
    printf("Enjoy your shell!\n");
    system("/bin/bash");
}

void vulnerable_function(char* string) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, string);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
[13:01:33][/tmp]$ make test
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘not_called’:
test.c:2:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
     printf("Enjoy your shell!\n");
     ^
test.c: In function ‘vulnerable_function’:
test.c:8:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
     strcpy(buffer, string);
     ^
[13:01:35][/tmp]$ gdb -q ./test
Reading symbols from ./test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) print not_called 
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x4005c0 <not_called>
(gdb) quit
[13:01:45][/tmp]$ ./test "$(python -c 'print "A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\xc0\x05\x40\x00"')"                 
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test "$(python -c 'print "A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\xc0\x05\x40\x00"')"
[13:01:48][/tmp]$ ./test "$(python -c 'print "A"*0x59 + "BBBBBBBB" + "\xc0\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"')"
[13:01:57][/tmp]$ ps | grep $$  
24471 pts/2    00:00:00 zsh
```

I assumed that my first attempt failed because addresses are 64-bit on my platform, so I decreased 0x6c to 0x59 in the "A" NOP sled, added four "B"'s and four zeros. Then the program clearly exited immediately, but my shell is still not bash. What happened? Here's an strace log:

```
execve("./test", ["./test", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"...], [/* 73 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x77a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f827bc8f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=182012, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 182012, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f827bc62000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\36\342\2736\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2096496, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x36bbe00000, 3920480, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x36bbe00000
mprotect(0x36bbfb4000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x36bc1b3000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b3000) = 0x36bc1b3000
mmap(0x36bc1b9000, 16992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x36bc1b9000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f827bc61000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f827bc5f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f827bc5f740) = 0
mprotect(0x36bc1b3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x36bbc1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f827bc62000, 182012)          = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Tested on Fedora 20.

Comment: I just realized that the \x00 wouldn't go into argv anyway.

Comment: Added the link to the tutorial.

Comment: someone on #security at irc.freenode.net pointed me out that I didn't compile with -m32 -fno-stack-protector. Still, I'm wondering what happened.